# Perturbation propagation in the Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-statistics

Take the 1D Ising model: A chain of spins (each with two neighbours) with spin values up or down. We start off with all spins up and for simplicity we assume an infinite system. 
At the location $i$ we perturb the system by flipping the spin to the value down. As there are no external fields to consider nor are there thermal fluctuations, the Hamiltonian is simplified to the interaction of neighbouring sites. With $c$ to denote the configuration of the whole chain, we have:
$$
H(c) = -\sum_{\langle i,j \rangle} J_{ij} \sigma_i \sigma_j
$$

With $J_{ij} > 0$ that is, the spins favor being aligned. One caveat that differs this problem from the usual case of 1D Ising: We consider discrete time steps, and moreover once a spin has been flipped it can never be undone. So e.g. as we perturbed spin $i$ and flipped it, it can no longer be reversed to spin up. Consequently, this means in the longtime limit, all spins will have been turned downward.

The question: Given that the interaction energy is finite, the perturbation caused at $i$ will not instantaneously flip all spins downward, instead we expect a finite propagation speed for this perturbation throughout the chain. Given that at each time step $t,$ starting at $t=0,$ either a neighbouring spin is flipped (so either $i+1$ or $i-1$ at $t=0$) or they remain unchanged. As a function of the strength of the interaction $J$ can we determine the rate (in time steps $t$) at which the fluctuations propagate starting from site $i$?

Comment: This is not really an Ising model, as you say, but rather something you defined. It's up to you to define the dynamics on it. Actually, even for the original Ising the dynamics can be defined in various ways.

Comment: Why should a flipped spin flip the other spins?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch through the neighbouring ferromagnetic (J>0) interaction. That is, the flipped ith spin eventually flips its neighbour, then this neighbour respectively flips its own neighbour. With the added constraint that once a spin flipped it cannot be reversed again. But because J, the strength is finite, at each time step a spin flip will not necessarily occur. If J was infinite, the flip of the neighbour would occur with probability 1.

Comment: Ising interactions are diagonal.  They don't flip spins.  (It feels like you are thinking of some Metropolis-type dynamics *related* to $H$, but you never mention so.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch yes indeed it is similar to Metropolis. Regarding Ising interactions I'm completely confused now: if they don't flip spins what do they do? In other words how do they influence the time evolution of the system?

Comment: Then you should precisely describe what you are thinking of.  All Hamiltonians do the same: They evolv the system as $e^{iHt}$.  But if $H$ is diagonal in the $z$-basis, it will not flip spins, it will just give different phases to different classical configurations.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, your dynamics is Markovian, i.e. the probability of a configuration evolves according to the master equation
   $${\partial\over\partial t}P(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots)
   =\sum_{\{\sigma_1',\ldots\}} \big[P(\sigma')W(\sigma'\rightarrow\sigma)
   -P(\sigma)W(\sigma\rightarrow\sigma')\big]$$
or, in discrete time,
   $$P(\sigma,t+1)=P(\sigma,t)+\sum_{\{\sigma'\}}\big[P(\sigma')W(\sigma'\rightarrow\sigma)
   -P(\sigma)W(\sigma\rightarrow\sigma')\big]$$
where $W$ are the transition rates. You want the dynamics to involve only single-spins flips
   $$W(\sigma\rightarrow\sigma')=\sum_i \omega_i(\sigma_i\rightarrow\sigma_i')
   \ \!\prod_{j\ne i}\delta_{\sigma_j,\sigma_j'}$$
You impose the condition that the spins can only be flipped once:
   $$\omega_i(\downarrow\rightarrow\uparrow)=0$$
Note that this condition is not compatible with detailed balance. Finally, you are left with a single transition rate to fix:
   $$\omega_i(\uparrow\rightarrow\downarrow)$$
You may choose something like
   $$\omega_i(\uparrow\rightarrow\downarrow)={1\over\tau}e^{\beta(J_{i-1,1}\sigma_{i-1}+J_{i,i+1}\sigma_i)}$$
to favor neighboring spins in the same direction. $\tau$ is an arbitrary characteristic time. My guess is that the speed that your are interested in is simply $1/\tau$ (or proportional to this).

Comment: Dear Christophe, very interesting, thanks a lot. If I may ask: but why do we have a choice for defining $w_i(\uparrow \rightarrow \downarrow)$? And how to interpret your choice in the last equation?

Comment: Please notice that the total energy change following a spin flip in this model (except the first) is always zero.